# How to prove that time is in sync on Linux servers

Tags: linux, redhat

I want to prove to another team that time is in sync on around 10 Linux servers. I have checked it and it looks good (ntp is setup etc). But they need some kind of validation.

Developers are claiming some piece of their code is not working and they suspected it tied to time sync.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Ask them what they want to see?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: It sounds like _they_ need to be proving to _you_ that time sync is the problem.

Comment: ha ha agreed. Already done that but it keeps coming back to me :(

Comment: You need to ask them to be more specific, then.

Comment: Had you considered setting up all the systems as NTP peers of each other?  That will help keep the time in tighter sync, especially if you're pulling time from pool.ntp.org (the public pool has some rather surprising variance at times in the time offsets).  Normally I'd set up a mesh topology for the peering, but with 10 systems I'd probably set up a ring (that is, each server has two symmetrical peers, arranged so that it forms a cycle in both directions).

Answer (score 3):

If you have *at least* 3 trusted time sources for your ntp client to sync to. If the output of something like `ntpq -p` shows them all in sync with the local host, then you're good - not a whole lot more you can do beyond that.

BTW, having 3 or more clocks to sync to is important. There is an old saying "A man with 2 watches never knows what time it is." It's true. If you have two time sources, you can never trust either of them to be true. You need at least 3 so that a consensus can be formed.

Comment: And better yet, use 4 time sources like the BCP documents for NTP recommend, so that if one goes down, you still have three good ones.

Answer (score 3):

Setup an NTP daemon on all the systems and properly configure it.  Also verify that your timezones are properly configured, both in the OS, and any software you are running (eg php config, and others).

Setup a monitoring system like nagios/icinga/etc, and use the [check_ntp_time](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_ntp_time.html) plugin to check the status of time on all your systems.  If you setup the right graphing plugins you can even make nice graphs showing the time offsets.

If you don't want/need a full monitoring system, you could just install the monitoring tools, and occasionally run the check_ntp_time via a script in cron or something and log/email the results or something.  Maybe just put a script somewhere that these devs can directly run and see the results.

Here is an example.  This checks the time of my linux desktop against the time of my router, with a warning if the offset is greater than a second, or error if greater than 5.

```
# check_ntp_time -H 10.1.1.1 -w 1.0 -c 5.0
NTP OK: Offset 0.004163891077 secs|offset=0.004164s;1.000000;5.000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take a screenshot of the `date` command between the servers.
Put the windows side-by-side and launch the command on the servers simultaneously.

If that's not enough... it's definitely their problem :)